# how to send data as post request and move to particular url in spring mvc

Tags: java, angularjs, http, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a spring mvc application with angular js on the Ui.

I have the following requirement where in

I get details from user (Consider a product ,amount)

I need to send the details to a payment gateway as post request  along with the redirection to the payment gateway website

Right now we send the details to the UI built on angular js and the Ui sends a  post request to the payment gateway and we enter the payment gateway website

As we have lot of sensitive data sent to the UI we wanted to implement the redirection to payment gateway along with the post request on the server side so as to be secure.

I have not been able to do this using controllers in spring mvc

I have tried the following methods

1] forward://website name (As this does not work for url outside the application)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/serverRedirection",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {

        RechargeDto rechargeDto = new RechargeDto();
        rechargeDto.setAmount("500");
        rechargeDto.setProvider("AT");
        rechargeDto.setMobile("9892948061");
        logger.info("Entered recharge controller");
        String message = "Invalid from app";

        request.getSession().setAttribute("amount", rechargeDto.getAmount());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("mobile", rechargeDto.getMobile());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("provider", rechargeDto.getProvider());

        PauDto pauDto = rechargeService.passToPayu(Float.parseFloat(rechargeDto.getAmount()), 2l, "9898989898");
        request.setAttribute("key", pauDto.getKey());
        request.setAttribute("txnid", pauDto.getTxnid());
        request.setAttribute("service_provider", pauDto.getService_provider());
        request.setAttribute("firstname", pauDto.getFirstname());
        request.setAttribute("amount", pauDto.getAmount());


        return "forward:https://website";
    }
```

2] redirect(Using Redirect attributes with redirect:// also has not helped as the application is redirected to payment gateway but no data is sent (as redirect cannot be used to forward request)

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/serverRedirection",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String myMethod(RedirectAttributes  request,HttpServletRequest req) {

        RechargeDto rechargeDto = new RechargeDto();
        rechargeDto.setAmount("500");
        rechargeDto.setProvider("AT");
        rechargeDto.setMobile("9892948061");
        logger.info("Entered recharge controller");
        String message = "Invalid from app";


        PauDto pauDto = rechargeService.passToPayu(Float.parseFloat(rechargeDto.getAmount()), 2l, "9898989898");
        pauDto.getService_provider());
        request.addAttribute("firstname", pauDto.getFirstname());
        request.addAttribute("amount", pauDto.getAmount());


        return "redirect:https://website";
    }
```

Is there any way to achieve this or is there any alternative way .

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in such cases a form is built in the UI with hidden input fields for the payload (token, price, etc.   - depends on your payment gateway), form action is set directly to be the payment gateway's URL, then just submit the form.

Comment: Is this not a security concern as the user can view the salt the key sent to payment gateway or any other way to ensure security

Comment: Well, in that form there is really nothing the current buyer should not see. Generally, the payment gateway provider gives you some sort of a salt and and an algorithm (or even read-made code) on how to generate a hash from that salt and purchase data. Normally, you only send via the form the purchase data (products, quantity, price, buyer info, etc.) and that generated hash. Not your private salt.